# "XYZ caterers is.." or "XYZ caterers are.."?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

In the following statement, which one is grammatically correct?

> XYZ caterers **is** on to something big

OR

> XYZ caterers **are** on to something big

I thought that it should be 'are' as caterers is plural. But it has been suggested that I might be wrong. What do you think?

Comment: In practice, I suspect that even Americans (who favour companies, families, and other such groups *always* being singular) might be more inclined to accept the plural in this case (but they can be pretty dogged once they have a grammatical principle between their teeth! :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the links to the duplicate questions. I wasn't sure how to go about searching something like this, so I posted the question thinking that I might get pointed in the right direction. That's what happened :)